# batch script - map network drives by computer name

Tags: windows, batch-file, network-drive

I am trying to modify a current script that is executed as logon script by domain GPO.  I have a special case where if users log into a specific machine on the domain, I need to map different network drives.  Otherwise all other computers load the basic drive mappings.

I have tries both of the following without any success:

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME% | %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\find.exe /i "VMMACHINE" > nul:
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto VMMACHINE-DRIVES
```

and I have tried

```
if %COMPUTERNAME% EQU "VMMACHINE" goto VMMACHINE-DRIVES
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please read how you can format your questions/answers (code for example), this helps a lot http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
if "%COMPUTERNAME%" == "VMMACHINE" goto VMMACHINE-DRIVES
```

Add `"` to interpret `%COMPUTERNAME%` as a string and `==` for string comparison.

Comment: thanks for the help.  Adding the "" around %COMPUTERNAME% did the trick it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax will work if you have both sides enclosed in double quotes and the case is correct for the two strings.

```
if "%COMPUTERNAME%" EQU "VMMACHINE" goto :VMMACHINE-DRIVES
```

This should work also.  Your code looked fine apart from the : on nul: which may work but is not often used.  This uses the errorlevel operator && and the complement is ||

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME% | find.exe /i "VMMACHINE" > nul && goto :VMMACHINE-DRIVES
```